# Python Selenium: Click on "next page" button

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

How can I click on this "Next Page" button of a table? Everything I tried returned "Element  is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click".

HTML of element:

```
<li title="Next Page" tabindex="0" class=" ant-pagination-next" aria-disabled="false"><a class="ant-pagination-item-link"><i aria-label="icon: right" class="anticon anticon-right"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" class="" data-icon="right" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M765.7 486.8L314.9 134.7A7.97 7.97 0 0 0 302 141v77.3c0 4.9 2.3 9.6 6.1 12.6l360 281.1-360 281.1c-3.9 3-6.1 7.7-6.1 12.6V883c0 6.7 7.7 10.4 12.9 6.3l450.8-352.1a31.96 31.96 0 0 0 0-50.4z"></path></svg></i></a></li>
```

I'm only used to click in buttons like this, but I don´t know how to adapt:

```
driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'test')]"))).click()
```

Bonus question: How can I know if I reached the last page?

Edit: I just took a print screen of the element + Inspect element code. Hope it helps

[Element to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPugw.png)

Comment: You don't even have a button element in the HTML you've shown so why are you searching for one? You need to know the basics of HTML and some XPATH to be able to scrape web pages.

Comment: the exception will list the element that will receive the click.  Deal with that element first. (usually it's something on top of the element you are trying to click.)  Include the entire exception.  For last page, it depends on the site, but usually the "Next Page" link will be inactive.

Comment: Hello Justin Ezequiel and @pcalkins. I just took a print screen of the element that I want to click and its Inspection code (link in the main question). Could you see if it give you some insight? I'm a beginner in web scrapping and would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution that's working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"ant-spin-container"))).find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Next Page"]').click()
```